# Communication with QThread not working with Signals / Slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread, qobject

I followed this tutorial for `QThreads`:
http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

The only problem I am having is killing the `QThread`. I have a flag in the `process()` loop of the worker object that I push into my `QThread` instance that is called `m_ShouldSendFrames`. If that flag is flipped to false, then my processing loop breaks and the worker object emits the `finished()` signal.

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to get my worker object in the `QThread` to receive my `stopSendingFrames()` signal from the main thread. I connect that ( and the connection returns 'true' ) like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(stopSendingFrames()), m_UdpWorkerBlended, SLOT(stopFrames()),Qt::QueuedConnection); // Stop broadcasting
```

In my `killUdpThread` function, I'd like to emit the `stopSendingFrames()` signal and have the `m_UdpWorker` object get it. But it never does! The only way I can get that flag to change is to do this in the `killUdpThread`:

```
m_UdpWorkerBlended->stopFrames();
```

That however, is unsafe and randomly crashed because it is not called from the `QThread` that the worker is running in.

I've also tried the `invokeMethod` way - but it never fires the slot either:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_UdpWorkerBlended,"stopFrames",Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Can someone please help me understand why I cannot call `invokeMethod` or use signals to fire my slot running in the worker object in the `QThread` but I can call it ( unsafely ) directly? Thanks!

Start thread function:

```
int UdpThreadController::startUdpThread(int frameType, int port, QString ip) {

    #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "Starting Thread! Frame type is: " << frameType;
    #endif

    // Check for type of frame to emit
    if ( frameType == 0 ) {

        #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
        qDebug() << "Frames are vl";
        #endif

        // Delete any existing threads / workers
        killUdpThread(0);

        // New objects
        m_UdpThreadBlended = new QThread();
        m_UdpWorkerBlended = new UdpWorker();

        // Assign Port and IP and Frame Type
        m_UdpWorkerBlended->m_ShouldSendFrames = true;
        m_UdpWorkerBlended->m_Port = port;
        m_UdpWorkerBlended->m_AddressToUse = ip;
        m_UdpWorkerBlended->m_FrameType = frameType;

        // Push into thread
        m_UdpWorkerBlended->moveToThread(m_UdpThreadBlended);

        // Connect signals
        connect(this, SIGNAL(stopSendingFrames()), m_UdpWorkerBlended, SLOT(stopFrames()),Qt::QueuedConnection); // Stop broadcasting
        connect(m_UdpThreadBlended, SIGNAL(started()), m_UdpWorkerBlended, SLOT(process()));
        connect(m_UdpWorkerBlended, SIGNAL(finished()), m_UdpThreadBlended, SLOT(quit()));
        connect(m_UdpWorkerBlended, SIGNAL(finished()), m_UdpWorkerBlended, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(m_UdpThreadBlended, SIGNAL(finished()), m_UdpThreadBlended, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        m_UdpThreadBlended->start();

        // All done
        return 0;
```

Kill thread function:

```
int UdpThreadController::killUdpThread(int frameType) {

    #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "Killing Thread! Frame type is: " << frameType;
    #endif

    // Check for type of frame to emit
    if ( frameType == 0 ) {

        // Delete any existing threads / workers
        if ( m_UdpWorkerBlended ) {

            #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
            qDebug() << "Emit signal to kill thread...";
            #endif

            // Stop broadcasting
            m_UdpWorkerBlended->stopFrames();

        }

        #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
        qDebug() << "Success ending UDP...";
        #endif

        // All done
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you emit the `stopSendingFrames` signal?

Comment: Hi, so in the killUdpThread function at the end of the listing, I tried to emit the signal stopSendingFrames in place of m_UdpWorkerBlended->stopFrames(). I replace the line in the listing with this: "emit stopSendingFrames()". The worker object never got the signal.

Comment: Is the worker thread "busy" when you are attempting to signal it? Signals can only be delivered once the thread is idle. Also, have you considered using `<QtConcurrentRun>` instead of threads? I find it to be much more convenient.

Comment: You don't happen to have an infinite loop of some sort in your `UdpWorker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I solved it by having a singleton that has a flag that the processing loop in my worker object in the QThread reads each loop iteration. It is protected by a QReadWrite lock.

```
int UdpThreadController::killUdpThread(int frameType) {

    #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "Killing Thread! Frame type is: " << frameType;
    #endif

    // Check for type of frame to emit
    if ( frameType == 0 ) {

        // Delete any existing threads / workers
        if ( m_UdpWorkerBlended ) {

            #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
            qDebug() << "Setting flag to kill thread...";
            #endif

            // Stop broadcasting
            m_Lock.lockForWrite();
            m_ShouldSendFramesBlended = false;
            m_Lock.unlock();

        }

        #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
        qDebug() << "Success ending Blended UDP...";
        #endif

        // All done
        return 0;

bool UdpThreadController::shouldContinueSendingFrames(int frameType) {

    #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "Checking if we should continue processing: " << frameType;
    #endif

    // Check for type of frame to emit
    if ( frameType == 0 ) {

        m_Lock.lockForRead();
        #if SINGLETON_CAMERA_UDP_DEBUG
        qDebug() << "Should continue Blended: " << m_ShouldSendFramesBlended;
        #endif
        bool shouldBroadcast = m_ShouldSendFramesBlended;
        m_Lock.unlock();

        // All done
        return shouldBroadcast;

    }
```